# Scala: Add values to sortedSet or array using for loop

Tags: scala

For a specific application I need to add integers from a non-sorted array to an empty `sortedSet` using a for loop. (Or to a new array which is sorted). I know this can be done avoiding loops but I want to use a loop in this instance.

This code seems broadly right:

```
def minFor(r: Array[Int]): Int = {
    var itsSorted = collection.SortedSet.empty[Int]
    for(i <- 0 to r.length)
      itsSorted = itsSorted + i
}
```

But no matter how I tweak it I always end up with a mismatch error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Int
           for(i <- 0 to r.length)
```

How do I return a sorted array or set via a loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function `minFor` should return `Int`. But your last statement in the function

```
for(i <- 0 to r.length)
  itsSorted = itsSorted + i
```

returns `Unit`. So compiler complains that types do not match. 
To return the actual sorted set you should change your function as:

```
def minFor(r: Array[Int]) = {
  var itsSorted = collection.SortedSet.empty[Int]
  for(i <- 0 to r.length)
    itsSorted = itsSorted + i
  itsSorted
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I understand that the Unit type is not correct. But I don't know how to return the desired data type - a sorted array or set - correctly. I'm new to  Scala.

Comment: I have updated the answer. You can put itsSorted.head if you need to return only minimum element, or itsSorted.headOption if your Array can be empty.